# Why is this hyperlink rollover code not working, any ideas?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, office365, user-defined-functions

I am trying to use hyperlink rollover technique/UDF to highlight a cell with an interior colour when I roll over it. The cells are consecutive down a column so have included in the function to colour the cell that's being hovered over, and clear the one below for scrolling up or one above if the user scrolls down.

Here's what I'm putting the the cell to be rolled over:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(@HighlightCell(ROW(),COLUMN()),"UNTAXED"),"UNTAXED")
```

and here is the UDF function code which resides in a module:

```
Public Function HighlightCell(iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer)

Dim strRef As Range

strRef = Sheet1.Cells(iRow, iCol).Address

    With strRef.Interior
    
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 13382451
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    
    strRef = strRef.Offset(-1, 0)

            .Pattern = xlNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    
    strRef = strRef.Offset(1, 0)
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            
    End With

End Function
```

My issue is that it isn't working! It should be triggering the function when I mouse over the cell, and I can't figure out why it isn't. I've found it quite hard to get my head around the rollover technique, but I thought I'd cracked it ... obviously not, I must be missing something.

I based it on Jordan Goldmeier's blog https://optionexplicitvba.blogspot.com/2011/04/rollover-b8-ov1.html
in the Option Explicit blog (2011) and I followed all his steps but it just won't trigger the code when I roll over. I looked at his fun Rollover Snake example http://files.chandoo.org/free/RollOver2.xlsm on Chandoo's site, and I did notice he had put an @ sign before the name of the function in the cell hyperlink formula, but adding that didn't do it (not sure why he did that actually I never saw it elsewhere or in his tutorial).

So I'm at a loss and I really need it to work for a project I am trying to get done today,so if anyone has any ideas or can point me in the right direction I'd be eternally grateful.

Thanks and regards, Mark

Comment: Remove .Address from this line: strRef = Sheet1.Cells(iRow, iCol).Address and add set at the beginning. Result: set strRef = Sheet1.Cells(iRow, iCol)

Comment: Thanks ofr that Ricardo, I actually figured it out in the end, but appreciate the help.